# Save uploaded picture to static/pictures in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Edit:
After further investigation it seems pretty obvious that I can't write to /static. I need to write the files elsewhere and direct the Thymeleaf to read from that location.

I am trying to upload a picture to my spring boot application, placing it in static/pictures so that the thymeleaf html page can read the picture. But I am unable to find out how to specify the path to that folder.

There is no problem saving the file to System.getProperty("user.dir");

```
//working
private String userDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
//Not working
private String userDirectory = "/static/pictures";
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
```

I would like the upload path to point to /static/pictures but will always get
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException no matter how I define the path.

```
        // Get the file and save it somewhere
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get( uploadPath + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //return "redirect:/uploadStatus";
    return "index";
}
```

I have also tried setting upload.path in the properties file.

```
upload.path=/META-INF/resources/static/pictures/
```

Comment: You can't write files to `/resources` once your application is bundled as a jar.
You can instead tell thymeleaf to look in multiple locations

Comment: At least it leads me in the right direction. Will look at bit deeper.

Comment: You can always upload it to a different directory and get it via : 
`response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);//Or IMAGE_JPG_VALUE etc...
IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file), response.getOutputStream());`

Answer (score 0):

I use a static helper to do this like with `org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils` class

```
public static File getResourceAsFile(String relativeFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return ResourceUtils.getFile(String.format("classpath:%s",relativeFilePath));

}
```

And use like

```
File dir=getResourceAsFile("/static/pictures/");
```

Comment: This seems to look for a file. I have a file uploaded to the spring boot and want to store it.

Comment: I didn't get it. You can get the folder and save in that folder with fileName. I've edited

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/static/pictures/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not exist

Comment: do you've `static/pictures` in your resources folder?

Comment: Yes I have that folder and are serving pictures that are static from it.

Comment: Do I have to configure the application somehow to find that path?

Comment: `classpath:` will search for folders in the class path of the jar if you've it or a war.

Comment: Can you post the statcktrace?

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you will need to add an extra path separator,

i.e.

```
private String userDirectory = "/static/pictures/";
```

or

```
Path path = Paths.get(uploadPath + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
Files.write(path, bytes);
```

Since in your question as written you would end up with something like

```
"/static/picturesfilename"
```

rather than

```
"/static/pictures/filename"
```

Be aware also that what you are doing is *extremely risky*.  The submitting user can, under certain circumstances, set getOriginalFilename(), and therefore write to

```
/static/pictures/../../etc/arbitrary
```

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18237